# How to change Laravel Container properties from within Service Provider?

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel binds pathis into the Container like so

```
$this->instance('path.lang', $this->langPath());
```

in bindPathsInContainer() in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php I'd like to change this path from within my Service Provider to something else.

I know that the container instance is accessible through $this->app from within a Service Provider, and so thought I could do

```
$this->app->instance('path.lang', 'my/path');
```

This however returns "class instance does not exist." Can anyone explain what's going on here?
Also, why does referencing ANY property of the container,  as in

```
$this->app->someProperty
```

lead to this error? Is there a way to edit someProperty from within a service provider? NB: I know this can be done by extending \Illuminate\Foundation\Application, as explained [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-lang-from-another-path) but I'd like to do this from without having to touch Laravel's default files.

Answer (score 0):

I think the path has to be absolute:

```
php artisan tinker
app()->instance('path.lang', '/home/user/you/project/something/something/that/exists);
```

You can also try it like that in your AppServiceProvider:

```
$this->app->instance('path.lang', $this->app->resourcePath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'mylang');
```